# VB.NET - Drawing upscaled graphics bleeds

Tags: vb.net

When I try to upscale a portion of an image in VB.NET, the source rectangle seems to bleed over.

```
    BMP1 = Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\TST.png")

    Dim G As Graphics = PictureBox3.CreateGraphics
    G.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
    G.DrawImage(BMP1, New Point(0, 0))
    G.Dispose()

    G = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
    G.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
    G.DrawImage(BMP1, New Rectangle(0, 0, 256, 256), 
                      New Rectangle(0, 32, 32, 32), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    G.Dispose()

    G = PictureBox2.CreateGraphics
    G.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
    G.DrawImage(BMP1, New Rectangle(0, 0, 256, 256), 
                      New Rectangle(0, 32, 31, 32), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    G.Dispose()
```

---

**VB.NET Test Image Results:**
[image: VB.NET Test Image Results]

---

As you can see, when upscaled to 8x, the image borrows red pixels from the neighboring cell. When I tried to adjust the source box by 1 pixel, the upscaled image seemed to lose two pixels instead of one.

My question is, how can I reproduce the stretching behavior from VB6?

---

**VB6 Test Image Results:**

[image: VB6 Test Image Results]

---

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer was to call DrawImage with RectangleFs instead of Rectangles, and then to subtract a magic number of 0.5 from the X and Y value of the source rectangle. This scales the image perfectly.

```
G.DrawImage(BMP1, New RectangleF(0, 0, 256, 256), 
                  New RectangleF(-0.5, 31.5, 32, 32), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```